# AngularJs $mdDialog close disables page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, freeze, mddialog

**I have a problem when closing mdDialog,** 
**here is the closePop**
I tried to use .hide() function but I have the same problema
`{
            $mdDialog.cancel();
            // $mdDialog.hide();
                       }`

When I hit the close button on the Dialog, the main view kinda freeze, the ng-click does not work anymore, here is the template:  `

```
<!--<div layout="row" class="tab-body room-tab-item" layout-wrap>-->

    <div elem-ready="$ctrl.loadData($ctrl.broadcaster.id)"></div>
<div class="calendar-tab-header"> Click on a date to add it into your time table</div>
<div>Items are displayed in your current time zone.</div>
    <div class="calendar-tab-success">{{$ctrl.success}}</div>
    <div class="calendar-tab-error">{{$ctrl.error}}</div>
    <table class="calendar-tab-my-timetable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date and Hour</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


        <button ng-repeat="schedule in $ctrl.schedules" ng-click="$ctrl.checkIn(schedule.id)">
            <td><div class="calendar-tab-date">{{schedule.date}}</div>
                <div class="calendar-tab-hour">{{schedule.startHour}}:00</div>
            </td>
            <!--<td>{{game.release}}</td>-->
        </button>



</div>
```

`
**the checkIn function only loads the modal, on the first click it works but when I use the close modal function, it closes the modal, but I cannot click again on the buttons to show the modal again, I think it disables the ng-click**

```
    $mdDialog.show({
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'modal.view.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                // targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                scope: $scope
            }).then(function (scope) {
            }, function () {});
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What probably happens is that the modal background layer is still present and on top of the rest of the page and therefore your click event doesn't cascade to the button element.Try setting `clickOutsideToClose: true` and see if the problem persists. Maybe a library bug?

Comment: I did that but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

**preserveScope: true**

```
 $mdDialog.show({
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'modal.view.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                // targetEvent: ev,
                preserveScope: true,
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                scope: $scope
            }).then(function (scope) {
            }, function () {});
```